# Crystal Report how to sum columns group by date

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, crystal-reports

I have a query in c# . I can see datas in datagridview. Here is my code

```
select welding_date
, (select SUM(mat_2_size) 
from fabrication_table fab_2 
where fab_1.welding_date = fab_2.welding_date 
and (fab_2.welder_1 like '%" + welder + "%' or fab_2.welder_2 like '%" + welder + "%'))as 'TOTAL 
SUM'
,(select SUM(mat_2_size) 
from fabrication_table fab_2 
where mat_2='AS' and fab_1.welding_date = fab_2.welding_date 
and (fab_2.welder_1 like '%" + welder + "%' or fab_2.welder_2 like '%" + welder + "%')) 
as 'SUM OF AS'
,(select SUM(mat_2_size) 
from fabrication_table fab_2 
where mat_2='SS' and fab_1.welding_date = fab_2.welding_date  
and (fab_2.welder_1 like '%" + welder + "%' or fab_2.welder_2 like '%" + welder + "%'))as 'SUM OF SS'
,(select SUM(mat_2_size) 
from fabrication_table fab_2 
where mat_2='CS' and fab_1.welding_date = fab_2.welding_date 
and (fab_2.welder_1 like '%" + welder + "%' or fab_2.welder_2 like '%" + welder + "%')) as 'SUM OF CS' 
from fabrication_table fab_1 
where welding_date between @date1 and @date2 
group by welding_date order by welding_date
```

Here is my result on datagridview

http://enderaric.com/calisma/q.PNG

Now I want to see this table on Crystal Report. This an emergancy statement!

summary of my question i have a table included mat_2_size ,mat_2 ,welding_date , welder_1,welder_2 and i want to sum total mat_2_size a range between @date1 and @date2 ,total size where mat_2=CS or AS or SS. i want to display every line like this
Date , sum of total , sum of where mat_2='CS', sum of where mat_2='AS', sum of where mat_2='SS'

Comment: My brain has melted and dribbled out the side of my ear whilst I was attempting to understand this.

Although what I think you need to create is a "running total field"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this as your where statement:

```
where datediff(day,@date1,weldingdate) >= 0
  and datediff(day,weldingdate,@date2) >= 0
```